# C# interface inheritance and generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

While writing my program I stumbled upon a pretty annoying problem that I can't solve.

In my software I have:

```
public interface IAutomationComponent
{
}

public class AutomationEditCollection<T> : List<T> where T : IAutomationComponent
{
}

public class AutomationMenuCollection<T> : List<T> where T : IAutomationComponent
{
}

public interface IComponentContainer
{
    AutomationEditCollection<IAutomationComponent> Edits { get; }
    AutomationMenuCollection<IAutomationComponent> Menus { get; }
}

public interface IAutomationEdit : IAutomationComponent
{
}

public interface IAutomationMenu : IAutomationComponent
{
}

public class AutomationEdit : IAutomationEdit
{
}

public class AutomationMenu : IAutomationMenu
{
}
```

(I know that's a lot of abstraction that could be simplified, but I just want to get it to work first)

Now, I want to create an instance of a class implementing `IComponentContainer`, 
 having collections `AutomationEditCollection<AutomationEdit>` and `AutomationMenuCollection<AutomationMenu>`:

```
public class ElementContainer : IComponentContainer
{
    public AutomationEditCollection<AutomationEdit> Edits { get; } = new AutomationEditCollection<AutomationEdit>();
    public AutomationMenuCollection<AutomationMenu> Menus { get; } = new AutomationMenuCollection<AutomationMenu>();
}
```

So if `ElementContainer`, having `Edits = AutomationEditCollection<AutomationEdit>`, wants to implement `AutomationEditCollection`'s `Edits = AutomationEditCollection<IAutomationComponent>`it should be able to since `AutomationEdit` implements `IAutomationComponent`, but I get following errors:

> `ElementContainer.Edits' cannot implement
>   'IComponentContainer.Edits' because it does not have the matching
>   return type of 'AutomationEditCollection'.
>
> 'ElementContainer.Menus' cannot implement
>   'IComponentContainer.Menus' because it does not have the matching
>   return type of 'AutomationMenuCollection'.

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like you actually want `IComponentContainer` to be generic.  Side note you almost definitely don't want to inherit from `List<T>`

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to return the same type that is defined in the interface, it cannot be an inheriting type. This will be fixed in the next version of C# though. AutomationEditCollection<AutomationEdit> has to be AutomationEditCollection<IAutomationComponent>